# Regression with a latent variable covariate?

Tags: regression, latent-variable

I want to fit a regression

$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$

$X$ can be = 0,1 and 2, is unobserved, but for each observation, we have the probability that it is 0, 1 or 2 (it can be different for each observation).  The dataset is in the following form:

$Y_1$ = 1, $P(X_1 = 0) = 0.1$, $P(X_1 = 1) = 0.9$, $P(X_1 = 2) = 0$

$Y_2$ = 2, $P(X_2 = 0) = 0.4$, $P(X_2 = 1) = 0.1$, $P(X_2 = 2) = 0.5$

and so on..

I feel this question should be encountered a lot and there should be some ready to use package, but I cannot find it. Could anyone give me some suggestion?

Comment: You are telling us you just don't know how $X$ is associated with $Y.$  Why, then, do you believe it would be possible to impute it from values of $Y$?  There has to be more information available than suggested by this model.

Comment: I am not trying to impute X, I just want to estimate beta0 and beta1. If I know X, it is just a standard linear regression. The issue is that I don't observe X, but I know the probability that X equal to some value for each observation.

Comment: Because ordinarily it's impossible to measure a probability directly, could you explain how you determine the distribution of $X$ for each observation?

Comment: I agree in reality no one can really define X, but let say I am willing to assume it is correct and it is given for each observation. It is a data analysis project, not about probability theory.

Comment: The problem is that a correct data analysis needs to account for the uncertainties in estimating these chances.  Otherwise this *is* merely a probability/math question in which the conditional distribution of $X$ has been specified and you need to derive the regression of $Y$ on $X$ (which is a rather strange exercise!).